# Creating a number of integers by user request

Tags: c, numbers, int, declare

I recently started learning C and wanted to know if there was a way to declare some integers, with the value given by the user.
For example, the user types in 3. I would like to create 3 integers, example `a`, `b` and `c`. If the user types in 5, I'd like to create `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you use `array`?

Comment: What will you do with the integers afterwards? *you cannot do what you ask, but maybe there's a simple solution for what you ultimately want*

Answer (score 1):

You want to make an array because you cannot declare an undefined number of single variables.
 Since you are a beginner i will give you a complete answer you can compile it if you wish :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int* arr,number,i;
    printf("Give number value: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * number); // after the comment, it safeguards the code
    for(i=0;i<number;i++){
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

arr is a pointer variable and you use it as an array that has the size of int * number of variables you want.

Comment: `arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number);` would be better as `arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * number);`

Comment: Well why would it be better since he wanted int values in the array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  It's better because A) You don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.  It is completely unnecessary and can hide an error on older compilers which allow implicit int. No experienced C programmer casts the return value of `malloc`. B) you use `sizeof(*some_ptr)` instead of `sizeof(int)` because it safeguards your code a bit.  If the type of `some_ptr` changes in the future you don't have to change the `sizeof` part as well.  It has the same effect; the compiler knows the type of the expression `*some_ptr`.

Comment: Indeed you are right but i used `sizeof(int)` so he can understand better how it works since he is a beginner; but you are right.
I asked because i thought he wouldn't change the type.

Comment: That's fair, but I would add and explain the better option. No reason to instill bad habits in a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an array of integers. When you received “`count`” value, you need to dynamically allocate the array of “`count`” items of type “`int`”.

For further details please take a look at `malloc ()` function: http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc

Answer (score 0):

I will make this easy for you.

What you can create is an array. An array is essentially a range of elements stored inside one name. If your not sure how to make/use arrays for your example... here is an example.

```
int main (void){
int i; //counter
int totalIntegers
int arrayVariableName[100]; //array that can store any amount(100 for this case)
                            //of variables inside.
printf("Enter total amount of variables");
    scanf("%d", &totalIntegers); //collect what the user types, pretend you type 5

for(i=0;i<totalIntegers;i++){ //this will loop 5 times from same example.
   printf("enter a number: ");
     scanf("%d",&arrayVariableName[i]); //will store numbers in array 0(which 
                                        // is holding the integer inside a), 
                                        // array 1(holding b), array 2(holding c)       
                                        //array 3(holding d), array 4(holding e).
   }

}
```

With an array and for loop, you can set the total amount which will allow user to punch in numbers that many times. If for instance you type 7 inside of 5, you can hold 7 variables (a,b,c,d,e,f,g). If you plan to make more than 100 integers, change it inside the array declaration. There is a method to set the limit to a unique amount you desire, the answer above me shows you how, look at it for reference.

To learn more, simply youtube search "array tutorial in c".

Comment: He'd be better of using dynamic allocation.  If the user enters a value > 100 your example results in UB.